# How to show advanced search in a mobile view? And also how to take a care of utilizing the space of a mobile screen?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, user-research, interface, user-centered-design

I am trying to get a solution for the mobile version of a web layout for an advanced search which includes dropdowns, filters, checkbox and toggle buttons. I tried to get it in the responsive format but the elements are coming out very small or big in a mobile view. Also utilizing space in the mobile view is also becoming a task.
Here is a wireframe of the web layout of the advance search.
[image]

Comment: What are all those XXXXXX's in your image? What are they supposed to present?

Comment: Those are just the titles of the data that needs to be represented. this is just the reference image so don't look into details. Its just to give the idea of the layout.

Comment: Danielillo's answer below is the most common way to perform what you are trying to do. I would also recommend digging in more to what your mobile user is trying to do - why are they using mobile instead of desktop at that moment - and remove options that the user isn't likely to need.

Answer (score 2):

More than an advanced search, this is a filter. You will find all the options you list with a responsive solution in the [MyFonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/sans-serif-fonts) filter where, while in the desktop version it remains always visible, in the mobile version it allows access through a button <kbd>[image]</kbd> allowing the use of the full screen

[image]